# How can I make an inherited property required in Code First fluent mapping?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following setup, abridged for brevity:

```
public abstract class AuditableEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Login Login { get; set; }  // Login that create this identity.
}

public class Login: AuditableEntity
{
    public Security Security { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionGuid { get; set; }
}

public class Security: AuditableEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

Now `Login` is only not required on the `Login` entity itself. In fact it doesn't belong in that table and I ignore it thus:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Login>().Ignore(l => l.Login);
```

I want it as required on all other tables, but when I e.g. try and make it required on `User`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Security.Security>().Property(p => p.Login).IsRequired();
```

I get a compile error, "The type 'Login' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T'". I note that I am allowed to use it as parameter 'T' in the `Ignore` call before, so I assume this is some other, hidden T.

My immediately apparent solutions are not very elegant:

1. Use an FK value and not a reference poperty for `Login` in  in `AuditableEntity`.
2. Create a new base class without `Login`, and another derived from that that adds `Login`, then inherit my Login class from the highest base, and all other classes from its immediate descendant.

Is there some better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using property syntax for native SQL properties. You actually want to use Nav property syntax such as `.HasRequired(t=>t.Login).WithMany()` or something similar

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843(v=vs.103).aspx, and the *Configuring a Relationship with One Navigation Property* section

Comment: Thanks. It looks like inheritance in this scenario might be a bit daunting for a novice like me, so I'm going with rather implementing `IAuditableEntity` on all my entities, but giving them their very own property declarations.